# ElasticSearch "match_all" slow with "from" > 1M with +10M documents

Tags: database, elasticsearch, bigdata

I have a simple one-field index with the following mapping:

```
"search": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "not_analyzed",
  "store": true
}
```

It's stored in 5 shards, and has over 10M documents (each of around 25bytes), and I have a webpage which iterates through them with the following query:

```
GET /searches/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "from": 1000000,
    "size":100
}
```

Here is some approximated data of the unjustified slowdown ("from" on the left, time in seconds on the right):

```
        0 -> 0.065
    1.000 -> 0.065
   10.000 -> 0.093
  100.000 -> 0.560 
1.000.000 -> 5.200
```

Is there any possible solution to get a constant execution time? Some magic query or setting or something. I have 3 more indexes in this same machine (all with millions of documents) and I don't want to maintain another database just to paginate properly through this data. In case I should migrate,.. which database will be good for this job?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
When I said "iterates" I meant "paginates". A user can request page 10 and suddenly page 1M. I'm not a native English speaker, sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: Can you explain the use case for this query? The order being returned from a match_all is arbitrary as it sets the score to 1 for all returned documents. So what's the purpose of starting from doc 1000000?

Comment: It's used to show a history of all the searches made on a site, and we want them appear well paginated so that google indexes the links to such searches. And while the documents have the same score, tell appear sorted in the same order they where indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a text from Elasticseach page.

> Deep pagination with from and size — e.g. ?size=10&from=10000 — is
>   very inefficient as (in this example) 100,000 sorted results have to
>   be retrieved from each shard and resorted in order to return just 10
>   results. This process has to be repeated for every page requested.

->[Elasticsearch Page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan)

You have to use scrolling for large data sets. Here is the [link.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew the term "deep pagination" and now I know what to look for. But scroll doesn't work in my case because a user can request pages arbitrarily without following any order (I've edited to clarify this). It looks I'll have to use another database...